# What width value corresponds to the Tufte fullwidth environment?

Tags: indentation, minipage, tufte

In [Tufte-LaTeX](http://code.google.com/p/tufte-latex/), I'd like to manually create a full-width environment using `minipage` rather than the package's `fullwidth` environment.

What width value should I supply to `minipage` to match that of the Tufte `fullwidth` environment's width?

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{minipage}{<width>}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{minipage} 

% The value for <width> above should make that paragraph identical this one
%\begin{fullwidth}
%     \lipsum[2]
%\end{fullwidth}

\lipsum*[3]

\end{document}
```

---

FWIW, I plan to use this primarily to create a full-width title block, if that matters for details of indentation and positoning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The length you are looking for is `\@tufte@fullwidth`. (Note: I'm assuming that you don't want to indent your `minipage`, therefore I added `\noindent` before it.)

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\fullwidthlength}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\fullwidthlength}{\@tufte@fullwidth}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\fullwidthlength}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{minipage} 

% The value for <width> above should make that paragraph identical this one
\begin{fullwidth}
     \lipsum[2]
\end{fullwidth}

\lipsum*[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent! What's the reason for the `\AtBeginDocument` (I notice from experimenting that it is essential). Also, apparently I can't have an `@` in a length?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius a) `tufte-handout` seems to calculate its lengths at the start of the document body, so the value of `\@tufte@fullwidth` is 0pt before that point b) I think it's like for commands -- you *can* use `@` for lengths, but these lengths can't be used directly in the document body.

Comment: That makes sense. Also: any idea how to get the vertical spacing between the manual full-width paragraphs to match that of the Tufte `fullwidth` environment?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius That's a `minipage` feature. :-) `\begin{minipage}[t]{\fullwidthlength}` is a partial solution; to correct the spacing after the `minipage` you'll have to sift through other `minipage` questions. (I don't have an answer right now.)

Comment: @lockstep has it exactly right. The `\@tufte@fullwidth` length isn't set until the document starts so that it can account for any customizations you make to the margins or paper size. You can use `\@tufte@fullwidth` directly in your document, but you'd need to surround it by `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: To fix the spacing, try adding a `\strut` to the beginning and end of your `minipage` contents. (Since `\lipsum` ends with `\par`, it'll insert a paragraph break and you'll get a blank line in the example, but this shouldn't be an issue in regular text.)

Comment: @godbyk: `\renewenvironment{fullwidth}{\noindent\begin{minipage}{\fullwidthlength}\strut}{\strut\end{minipage}}` gives me something that's just a bit shy of what it should be.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: If you're referring to the spacing after the regular `fullwidth` environment, then you can add `\unskip\par` immediately following `\end{fullwidth}` to bring it back in line.  See [this example document](https://gist.github.com/2052945).

Comment: @godbyk: I was referring to the way that `fullwidth` as defined in the Tufte package has a bit more vertical space top and bottom than regular paragraphs. The redefined version using `minipage` (with `\strut`) makes it just like a regular paragraph in that regard. I wasn't sure which was "correct" from a Tufte point of view.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: Ah, I understand. I'll look into getting the `fullwidth` environment to have the proper spacing. It was originally designed solely to allow us to have `figure*` and `table*` environments.

Comment: @godbyk: Thanks. This works for my purposes at the moment (I'm just full-width-ing the title, and never use `fullwidth` elsewhere), but that may change.