# Tufte-LaTeX Fullwidth with EasyList

Tags: tufte, easylist

I am trying to use `tufte-latex`'s `fullwidth` environment in some sections, but I can't get it to work with the `easylist`-package as it removes the indentation.

```
\documentclass[nobib]{tufte-handout}
\title{Test}
\author{Tester}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Section 1}
\begin{fullwidth}
\begin{easylist}[itemize]
& \lipsum
&& \lipsum
\end{easylist}
\end{fullwidth}

\section{Section 2}
\begin{easylist}[itemize]
& \lipsum
&& \lipsum
\end{easylist}

\end{document}
```

In the example, **Section 1** has the full width, but is missing the proper indentation. **Section 2** has the proper indentation, but is missing the `fullwidth`.

Comment: You could make a full width minipage with correct indentation, as in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48290/what-width-value-corresponds-to-the-tufte-fullwidth-environment

Comment: `easylist` doesn't like to be inside a `list` environment, which is how `fullwidth` is implemented: an `easylist` should be at the top level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `easylist` environment relies on `\hangindent` and `\hangafter` so it cannot be used inside an environment based on `list`, such as `fullwidth`, because in this environments `\parshape` is set, which prevails over `\hangindent` and `\hangafter`.

You can define a `fullwidtheasylist`, though.

```
\documentclass[nobib]{tufte-handout}
\title{Test}
\author{Tester}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{fullwidtheasylist}
 {\hsize=\dimexpr\hsize+\csname @tufte@overhang\endcsname\easylist}
 {\endeasylist}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Fullwidth}
\begin{fullwidtheasylist}[itemize]
& \lipsum[2]
&& \lipsum[2]
\end{fullwidtheasylist}

\section{Normal}
\begin{easylist}[itemize]
& \lipsum[2]
&& \lipsum[2]
\end{easylist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works great for a section that is just an easylist.  I sometimes put raw text and easy list together, but this works.