# tufte-book and marginfix

Tags: floats, margins, titlesec, marginpar, tufte

I want to apply this fix [Full width text shifts all marginfix-ed floats off the page to the right](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47960/full-width-text-shifts-all-marginfix-ed-floats-off-the-page-to-the-right) to the tufte-book document class, however I get an error whenever I use `\chapter`.

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\fullwidthlength}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\fullwidthlength}{\@tufte@fullwidth}}
\makeatother
\renewenvironment{fullwidth}{\noindent\begin{minipage}{\fullwidthlength}\strut}{\strut\end{minipage}}
\usepackage{marginfix}

\begin{document}
\chapter{My Chapter}
This is text before some full width text. The footnote that goes with it is way over there.\footnote{This note goes with the text before the full width text.}

\begin{fullwidth}This is some full width text. Its presence on a page using \texttt{marginfix} pushes all notes to the right off the page.\end{fullwidth}

This is some other text, after the full width text, and its note is also way over there.\footnote{This note goes with the text after the full width text.}

\end{document}
```

> ! Package titlesec Error: Entered in horizontal
>   mode.

The problem is probably in [tufte-common.def](https://github.com/Tufte-LaTeX/tufte-latex/blob/master/tufte-common.def) since `\chapter` makes use of `fullwidth`.

```
\titleformat{\chapter}%
  [display]% shape
  {\relax\ifthenelse{\NOT\boolean{@tufte@symmetric}}{\begin{fullwidth}}{}}% format applied to label+text
  {\itshape\huge\thechapter}% label
  {0pt}% horizontal separation between label and title body
  {\huge\rmfamily\itshape}% before the title body
  [\ifthenelse{\NOT\boolean{@tufte@symmetric}}{\end{fullwidth}}{}]% after the title body
```